# Javascript trigger on jquery html() ajax insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am inserting the following javascript function into my page using the jQuery command `html(data_in_here)`. How do I make it run the javascript code?

```
        echo 'window.onload = function(){';
            echo 'var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");';
            echo 'window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {';
                echo 'responsive: true,';
                echo 'maintainAspectRatio: false';
            echo '});';
        echo '}';
```

I assume it's not running because it is using window.onload?

Comment: For starters the onload event has already occurred if you are inserting this using jQuery so the function won't ever be called

Comment: How do I call it then?

Comment: Just remove the first and last lines of the code snippet you posted.

Comment: Please show how you are using this. Without a script tag it doesn't make much sense either. Inserting what is shown would simply insert it as text

Comment: Piggybacking on that, if for some reason you really do need to insert this with PHP, then I'd strongly recommend using a Heredoc or Nowdoc to drastically improve readability: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc